Issue refactoring if-else-if string.contains("X") to switch case (or better)

Include details about your goal:

I would like to refactor if-else-if string.contains("X") statements in java to switch case or a Map.

Show some code:

I have a piece of code, very simple, which looks like:
     public String question(String sentence) {
        if (sentence.contains("eat")) {
            return getFoodFromSentence(sentence);
        } else if (sentence.contains("drink")) {
            return getBeverageFromSentence(sentence);
        } else if (sentence.contains("drive")) {
            return getVehicleFromSentence(sentence);
        } else if (sentence.contains("travel")) {
            return getDestinationFromSentence(sentence);
    [...
        many many other else if
    ...]
        } else {
            return "sentence with unknown verb";
        }
    }

    private String getDestinationFromSentence(String sentence) {
        return ""; //some complex code to extract some info from the sentence
    }

    private String getVehicleFromSentence(String sentence) {
        return ""; //some complex code to extract some info from the sentence
    }
[... all the other actual handling methods ]

I wish to refactor this using a switch case:

Describe what I tried:

Using switch case:
   public String question(String sentence) {
        switch (???) { //issue here, I am not able to come up with the expression
            case (sentence.contains("eat")): // issue here, I am not able to have the cases representing the if
                return getFoodFromSentence(sentence);
            case (sentence.contains("drink")):
                return getBeverageFromSentence(sentence);
            case (sentence.contains("drive")):
                return getVehicleFromSentence(sentence);
            case (sentence.contains("travel")):
                return getDestinationFromSentence(sentence);
        [ ... the other case conditions ... ]
            default:
                return "sentence with unknown verb";
        }
    }

I also tried using the Map pattern, something like:
 public String question(String sentence) {
        Map<Predicate<String>, Function<String, String>> map =
                Map.of(s -> s.contains("eat"), s -> getFoodFromSentence(s),
                        s -> s.contains("drink"), s -> getBeverageFromSentence(s),
                        s -> s.contains("drive"), s -> getVehicleFromSentence(s),
                        s -> s.contains("travel"), s -> getDestinationFromSentence(s));
        return map.get(???).apply(sentence); // issue here, how to get the correct key of the map?
    }


Question:

May I ask how to resolve the issues of using the switch case?
Or maybe how to resolve the Map?
Are there other technique to refactor this  if-else-if string.contains("X")?

Did you try looking at the docs? - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

It's not possible with switch. With a map, you would need the Predicates as a value, or you build the predicates dynamically and only have string-action pairs in the map, selecting the value from the pair with a the matching key. You might want to look into the chain of responsibility pattern, maybe it can help you.

Create the map where the keys are "eat", "drink", ... and values are your functions. Then just iterate through all the pairs of the map in a loop with the contains(key) condition. If the condition is true, then execute the function from the value. This is better, because the sentence can contain several keys at once.

@knittl Actually, it is possible:  case String s when sentence.contains("eat"):  Voting to reopen.

@KonstantinMakarov Yes, exactly.

@VGR I stand corrected. I should spend some time playing with switch expressions.

case statements can make use of the when keyword:
public String question(String sentence) {
    switch (sentence) {
        case String s when sentence.contains("eat"):
            return getFoodFromSentence(sentence);
        case String s when sentence.contains("drink"):
            return getBeverageFromSentence(sentence);
        case String s when sentence.contains("drive"):
            return getVehicleFromSentence(sentence);
        case String s when sentence.contains("travel"):
            return getDestinationFromSentence(sentence);
        default:
            return "sentence with unknown verb";
    }
}


A switch block with constant cases is usually optimized at the compilation stage. I'm wondering what such a block unfolds into.

For the map-based approach, you could try this:
public String question(String sentence) {
    Map<String, Function<String, String>> map = Map.of(
            "eat", this::getFoodFromSentence,
            "drink", this::getBeverageFromSentence,
            "drive", this::getVehicleFromSentence,
            "travel", this::getDestinationFromSentence
    );
    for (Map.Entry<String, Function<String, String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (sentence.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            return entry.getValue().apply(sentence);
        }
    }
    return null;
}


Two problems with this approach: a) The iteration order is not guaranteed when using Map.of. So if a sentence contains more than one key, your approach may return a different value than what the OP has now. b) Map.of() supports at most 10 key-value pairs. However, the OP points out that he wants to cover more than the cases given in the example. Maybe use Map.ofEntries() here? Or a standard LinkedHashMap to avoid both problems?

@Asmir Good point. Since we don't really use any map-functionality, we could also just use a List of Entries (or some other tuple/pair-type).

A similar solution with the map approach of tobias_k only with a LinkedHashMap to guarantee the order and using streams and optionals to possibly improve the readability a bit:
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Example ex = new Example();

        String sentence1 = "What do you eat?";
        System.out.println(ex.question(sentence1));

        String sentence2 = "What do you drink?";
        System.out.println(ex.question(sentence2));

        String sentence3 = "What do you drive?";
        System.out.println(ex.question(sentence3));

        String sentence4 = "Where do you travel to?";
        System.out.println(ex.question(sentence4));

        String sentence5 = "What did you do yesterday?";
        System.out.println(ex.question(sentence5));
    }

    public String question(String sentence) {

        Map<String, UnaryOperator<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("eat",    this::getFoodFromSentence);
        map.put("drink",  this::getBeverageFromSentence);
        map.put("drive",  this::getVehicleFromSentence);
        map.put("travel", this::getDestinationFromSentence);

        return map.keySet().stream()
                           .filter(sentence::contains)
                           .findFirst()
                           .map(e -> map.get(e).apply(sentence))
                           .orElse("Sentence with unknown verb");
    }

    private String getFoodFromSentence(String sentence) {
        return "Haggis";
    }

    private String getBeverageFromSentence(String sentence) {
        return "IRN-BRU";
    }

    private String getDestinationFromSentence(String sentence) {
        return "Ring of Brodgar";
    }

    private String getVehicleFromSentence(String sentence) {
        return "Galloway";
    }
}

